# Facebook Timeline doesn't show up in profile section

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I am new to Facebook and found out about my "Timeline" but I don't have one I don't see it in my Profile and anywhere else. Is it possible that I deleted my Timeline or did I do something wrong?

How may this problem occur?

Comment: If you are not seeing your News Feed, please attach a screenshot in your question by clicking edit.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Timeline means News Feed. Whatever you are seeing in your News Feed that is called Timeline.